# Need help finding max min in array with MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am new to MIPS and I am really confused how to find max and min. It is giving me numbers but incorrect.

````
        loop:
            ble $t1, $s1, yeah
            j Exit
        yeah:
            sll $t1, $t1, 2  #t1 = j, s1 = i
            add $t0, $t1, $s5
            lw  $t0, 0($t0)
            blt $t0, $s6, targetmin #could be the problem
            bgt $t0, $s7, targetmax #could be the problem
            addi $t1, $t1, 1
            j loop
        targetmin:
            move $s6, $t0 #could be the problem

            j loop
        targetmax:
            move $s7, $t0 #could be the problem

            j loop

    ```
````

Comment: That's not the complete code necessary for reproducing the issue. Anyway, use the debugging features (breakpoints, single-stepping, etc) in one of the available MIPS simulators.

Comment: That's a pretty good start, though as noted already important parts of the code are not shown.  However, fyi, you are only capturing the max *if it is not also the min*, which may skip some elements re: max.  You might initialize $s6 and $s7 with the value of the first element before the loop to work past that.